# Confused about this solution in Leet code for Reverse Linked List

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I saw this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/description/) in Leet and wanted to try it. one of the solutions proposed was the one below, however, I am scratching my head a little bit. I do understand what's going on but I don't understand some behaviors.

```
var reverseList = function(head){
  
  var tmp = null;
  var newHead = null;
  
  while(head !== null){
    tmp = head;
    head = head.next; 
    tmp.next = newHead; 
    newHead = tmp; 
  }
  
  return newHead;
}
```

For the input of `[5,4,3,2,1]` we get this in each iteration

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5]
null
[1]

[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5]
[1]
[2,1]

[3,4,5]
[4,5]
[2,1]
[3,2,1]

[4,5]
[5]
[3,2,1]
[4,3,2,1]

[5]
null
[4,3,2,1]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

here what's I am confused about

1. why is `tmp = head; //tmp = [1,2,3,4,5]`
   but when `newHead = tmp // newHead = [1]` and not [1,2,3,4,5]
2. `head = head.next;` doesn't seem to affect the two lines after it, but if we move `head = head.next;`  to the last position, the code does not work

Comment: *"we get this in each iteration"*: the code doesn't print anything, and there are not arrays involved, so where do you get that output from?

Comment: I added console.log() after each line to see what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is `tmp = head; //tmp = [1,2,3,4,5]` but when `newHead = tmp // newHead = [1]` and not [1,2,3,4,5]

That is because between those two assignments, `tmp.next` has been reassigned. In the first iteration, `tmp.next` will be assigned `null`, so that effectively cuts the list short to just the node `tmp` itself.

> `head = head.next;` doesn't seem to affect the two lines after it, but if we move `head = head.next;`  to the last position, the code does not work

That's because it has to happen before `tmp.next` is assigned. If `head = head.next` has not happened before `tmp.next = newHead` is done, then `tmp` and `head` will still reference the same node, and thus `tmp.next = newHead` will mutate that same node. Hence, *after* that has happened `head.next` is no longer what it was before that assignment. This explains why `head = head.next` would not have the same effect anymore (and not the correct effect).

Comment: ```when we do head = head. next``` is it a deep copy?

Comment: No, it is an assignment of an object reference. No object is created.